# Email verification with random string generator and MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, forms

I have a slight problem with my email verivication code. I try to send the user a unique passcode ID. Used to login beside a username + password.

I built it using a random string key generator:

```
<?php
function passFunc($len, $set = "") {
    $gen = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $set = str_shuffle($set);
        $gen .= $set[0];
    }
    return $gen;
}
$passcode=passFunc(4, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789');
?>
```

Im using it like this: when the user submits the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="" id="" name="register">
    Email address <input type="text" name="username" id="username placeholder="E-Mail adres" maxlenght="50"><p>
    Repeat Email address <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Herhaal uw E-Mail adres"><p>
    Password <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Wachtwoord"><p>
    First name <input type="text" name="voornaam" id="voornaam" placeholder="Voornaam" maxlenght="15"><p>  
    Lastname <input type="text" name="achternaam" id="achternaam" placeholder="Achternaam" maxlenght="20"><p>
    Telephone number:* <input type="text" name="telefoonnummer" id="telefoonnummer" placeholder="Telefoon nummer" maxlenght="14"><p>
    Company <input type="text" name="bedrijf" id="bedrijf" placeholder="Bedrijf" maxlenght="50"><p>
    <input type="hidden" name="passcode" id="passcode" value="<?php echo $passcode; ?>">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Registreer">&nbsp;
    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-info" value="Reset formulier">
    <!-- Send email when successfully registered -->
```

Its about this piece of code that displays the random string into a hidden field it can be send with the email:

```
<input type="hidden" name="passcode" id="passcode" value="<?php echo $passcode; ?>">
```

But when i try to send it with this email form:

```
<?php
 $to = $_POST['username'];
 $subject = "Your account has been created";

 <!--- body of the email -->
 $body = $_POST['passcode'];
 $body = 'This is your passcode \n login at http://www.directofficesupport
 /login.php \n Regards, the Directofficesupport.com team.';
 <!--- end of email body -->

 $from = 'account@directofficesupport.com';
 (mail($to, $subject, $body, $form)) 
 ?>
```

It doesnt work.

but the funny thing is, that when the random string gets registered in the database. that does work, but the email doesnt.

I can't get it to work D:
Please help out.

Regards, 
Jesse

EDIT:

Um but one thing then. How do you put

```
$_POST['passcode']
```

in the middle of the sentence
do you need to do it like this?

```
$body =  '\n This is your passcode: $_POST['passcode'] . \n login at http://www.directofficesupport
/login.php \n Regards, t
```

- Jesse

Comment: Well right off the bat you are setting body = to the POST PASSCODE and in the next line setting it to something different maybe you want the .= to append it

Comment: It is to display a message aswell, please give me an example of how you can display a message AND the passcode

Comment: This is your passcode: ' . $_POST['passcode'] . ' ect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$to = $_POST['username'];
$subject = "Your account has been created";

<!--- body of the email -->
$body = $_POST['passcode'] . '\n This is your passcode \n login at http://www.directofficesupport
/login.php \n Regards, the Directofficesupport.com team.';
<!--- end of email body -->

 $from = 'account@directofficesupport.com';
 (mail($to, $subject, $body, $form)) 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use correct escape strings:

```
$body =  '\n This is your passcode: '. $_POST['passcode'] . '\n login at http://www.directofficesupport/login.php \n Regards, t...';
```

or ad a `.` to append to the original string:

```
$body = $_POST['passcode'];
$body .= 'This is your passcode \n login at http://www.directofficesupport/login.php \n Regards, the Directofficesupport.com team.';
//----^
```